# Counting symmetric unitary matrices with elements of equal magnitude

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $X$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric unitary matrix with elements of equal magnitude and the elements of the first row (and the first column, of course) are $1/\sqrt{n}$, i.e. $X_{j,k} = e^{i \phi_{j,k}}/\sqrt{n}$ with $\phi_{j,k}=\phi_{k,j} \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\phi_{1,k}=0$.
Prove (or disprove) that such matrix is unique up to permutations.

The background here is to get understanding of the set of bases in $\mathbb{C}^n$ with coordinates differ by phase factors only. The orthogonality relation $(v_j, v_k) = n^{-1}\sum_l \exp(i(\phi_{j,l}-\phi_{k,l})) = 0$ for $j \ne k$ is invariant with respect to $\phi_{j,k} \to \phi_{j,k}+\omega_j + \omega_k$. This would be great if the set could be obtained from a particular choice

$$X_{j,k} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{n} (j-1)(k-1)\right)$$

by permutations and the symmetry transformation.

The statement seems plausible since the matrix $X$ is determined by $n(n-1)/2$ phases with $n(n-1)/2$ constraints imposed by orthogonality relations. The proof, however, is lacking. I would greatly appreciate help in a form of proof/disproof or a strong hint.

Comment: If the elements of the first row and column are all ones, then the upper left entry of $XX^*$ is $n$, so $XX^*\ne I$, so $X$ is not unitary.

Comment: @Gerry: I think that was just a somewhat sloppy formulation; the formula right after it does include the factor $\sqrt n$.

Comment: Yes, sorry for inaccuracies. The important property of the matrix in question is that its elements have the same magnitude and therefore the whole matrix was thought with a common normalization factor.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix in question is not unique, at least not in all dimensions.

Consider your chosen matrix $X$ with $n=4$; this is the discrete Fourier matrix
$$X=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
1&i&-1&-i\\
1&-1&1&-1\\
1&-i&-1&i
\end{pmatrix}$$

Another matrix with $n=4$ that satisfies your criteria is the Hadamard matrix
$$H=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\
1&1&-1&-1\\
1&-1&-1&1\\
1&-1&1&-1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Because the two matrices share the same first row and column, they cannot be obtained from each other by multiplying rows or columns by phases.

Now, your statement is true when $n=1$ (trivially), $n=2$ (because the condition on the first row and column leaves only a single element to be determined), and $n=3$ (where the two possible matrices are equivalent up to a permutation of the final two rows or columns). The degree of freedom argument that you presented breaks down because all of the phases in $X$ depend on the same root of unity. So, one could still ask whether there are other dimensions for which your statement is true. For example, is it true for prime dimensions?

Comment: This is a very good observation. Apparently, there are such matrices that do not produce mutually unbiased bases and, perhaps, some kind of manageable description is possible after all.

Comment: The two matrices in this answer can both be used to form mutually-unbiased bases, as per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_unbiased_bases#Hadamard_matrix_method[1]) and the nice [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0610216) cited there.